# Connection with Java Spring, maven, oracle, hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to connect my maven project to an oracle database using spring and hibernate, this error is still showing up after many attempts to fix it, would you guys mind checking this out and guide me on what might be wrong?

[Error in CMD (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUnIV.jpg)

```
23:07:45,676 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringMVC].[SpringMVC]] (http--127.0.0.1-8088-1) Servlet.service() para servlet SpringMVC lanz¾ excepci¾n: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
```

My Application context:
[ApplicationContext.xml (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muz0x.jpg)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="ds" />
    <property name="URL"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080:test" />
    <property name="user" value="system" />
    <property name="password" value="3123312257" />
</bean>
```

My dependecy of Oracle

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My aplication.properties:

```
# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080:test
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=3123312257
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Comment: the port for oracle is usually 1521 and web application is 8080...please check the port for yoyr oracle db when you connect to it using your oracle sql client...

Comment: Though without any stack trace its not possible to tell definite reason...

Comment: @akshayapandey yes, I changed the port to 1521 and now the following error is displayed:

Comment: `23:55:49,597 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringMVC].[SpringMVC]] (http--127.0.0.1-8088-1) Servlet.service() para servlet SpringMVC lanz¾ excepci¾n: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

Comment: you shoudl verify if your SID  'test' exists in oracle or not..default is usually XE.  the conenctio string is of form jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>:<SID>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection parameter for host "localhost" and the port "8080" are really correct?

Please verify once.

Below code works fine for me. you can use the same and check if there is an oracle issue or your side.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
try {
Connection connection = null;

String serverName = "127.0.0.1"; //http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex
String portNumber = "1521";
String sid = "xe"; //xe

String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;

String username = "system";
String password = "password";

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");

while (rset.next()) 
{
System.out.println(rset.getString(1));
System.out.println(rset.getString(2));
}
stmt.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Hai " + e);
}
}
```

Comment: I changed the port to 1521 and now the following error is displayed:

`23:55:49,597 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringMVC].[SpringMVC]] (http--127.0.0.1-8088-1) Servlet.service() para servlet SpringMVC lanz¾ excepci¾n: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

Comment: refer this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/listener-refused-the-connection-with-following-error-ora-12505-tns-listener-d

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you very much!! I solved the biggest problem with your help

Answer (score 0):

After updating your port to 1521, you might need to update port in tnsnames.ora (might be placed in oracle\product\{version}\client_1\network\ADMIN).